# How to exclude a jQuery object from animation?

Tags: jquery

I have a script like this that performs an animation for a horizontal accordion. Whenever a different slide (li) on the accordion is opened it is put inside the 'active' object.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    active = $('ul li:first-child');

    $('ul li').click(
      function(){
        $(active).animate({width: '40px'}, { queue:false, duration:600 });
        $('div').fadeOut(100).delay(400).fadeIn(100);
        $(this).animate({width: '660px'}, { queue:false, duration:600});
        active = this;          
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

The animations all work great but the only problem is that when I click on the currently opened slide it runs this--

```
$('div').fadeOut(100).delay(400).fadeIn(100);)
```

How do I exclude the currently opened slide from running this? I've tried .not and :not but maybe I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Some HTML would help me better understand if you have it

Comment: I see a couple of severe problems in your code to begin with that are most likely unintended. The line that starts with `$('div')....` fades every div on the whole page on a click. Is that really what you want? Since you write that the animations work fine, maybe it is intended. Second, the line that starts with `$(active).click(function()...` binds a new event handler every time an li is clicked. There's no way you intended that. I believe what you want is to delete that line, and to `return false;` at the _end_ of the the function.

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe you meant to take the event as a parameter e and do this in your code: ` $('ul li').click(
      function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
[...]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting a guard clause before you animate anything...
something like

```
if (active == this) return;
```

as first line in the click handler function?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
if(this != active[0]) $('div').fadeOut(100).delay(400).fadeIn(100);
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a little known way of dealing with this very problem. Use the .not() function. You can use that to remove elements from the jQuery object.

I would do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    active = $('ul li:first-child');

    $('ul li').not('li.open').click(
      function(){
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(active).animate({width: '40px'}, { queue:false, duration:600 });
        $('div').fadeOut(100).delay(400).fadeIn(100);
        $(this).animate({width: '660px'}, { queue:false, duration:600});
        $(active).click(function() { event.StopPropagation(); });
        active = this;          
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

The important lines are .not('li.open') and then "$(this).addClass('open')".

You'll need to add a way off removing the 'open' class from all li's once the menu closes, but not knowing your HTML I can't tell you how best to do that.